# Illegal string offset After PHP Upgrade

Tags: php

> Warning [2] Illegal string offset 'title' - Line: 66

```
if(!isset($params['title'])) {
    $params['title'] = "Hidden Content";
  }
```

and Warning [2] Illegal string offset 'title' - Line: 3

```
  eval("\$return = \"".$templates->get("lock_wrapper")."\";");
```

**Please help!**

Comment: use this pattern.

`$param_title =  $params['title'];

if(!isset($params_title)) {
    $params_title = "Hidden Content";
  }`

Comment: Your eval should be 
  eval($return = $templates->get('lock_wrapper'));

Comment: now its showing 500 error .

Comment: Are you sure that `$params` is an array? I mean not a string?

Comment: here is the full code https://pastebin.com/rBZEmJc8